# Android alarmmanager multiple pending intents in a loop

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have a weekly schedule that are saved in TimeInterval objects, they work fine. I constructed a loop so I can set an alarm for each of them. My code does not work, what am i missing?

Further, how can i cancel these alarms from a BroadcastReceiver from another thread?

```
for(ArrayList<TimeInterval> day : days){
        for(TimeInterval ti : day){
            numberofintents++;
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChangeMode.class);
            i.putExtra("ringermode", ti.getRingerMode());

            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), id, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,ti.getMinute()%60);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,ti.getMinute()/60);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayofweek);
            Log.d(TAG, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24*7, pending);
            id++;
        }
        dayofweek++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First make an array list of pending intents,

```
public static ArrayList <PendingIntent> intentArray= new ArrayList <PendingIntent>();
```

then add pending intents to array list,

```
for(ArrayList<TimeInterval> day : days){
    for(TimeInterval ti : day){
        numberofintents++;
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChangeMode.class);
        i.putExtra("ringermode", ti.getRingerMode());

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), id, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        intentarray.add(pending);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,ti.getMinute()%60);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,ti.getMinute()/60);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayofweek);


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);


         id++;
    }
    dayofweek++;
}
```

Now your pending intents are stored in array list.

If you want to cancel an alarm,

```
alarmManager.cancel(intentArray.get(i));
```